# How to put figure caption on top?

Tags: tables, captions, positioning

I have a table that I have inserted as a figure in LateX because it was externally created. I would like to have the caption on top, but it is not working. Any suggestions?

```
\newline
\topcaption{\textbf{{Table 1}}
\newline
\includegraphics[origin=c, scale=0.74]{table1}
```

Comment: Either use a `table` environment and say `\caption` as usual or use `\captionof{table}{Your caption title}` -- this requires `caption` package. `\topcaption` is unknown to me, the `\newline` statements are weird

Comment: I have tried caption as usual and it didnt work. Also, this is not a typical latex table, hence the difficulty.

Comment: Well, than please provide minimal complete document, which show your problem.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the issue could be solved by the O.P. (in an unspecified manner, however)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A common misunderstanding by many beginners to LaTeX is that a `tabular` like environment can only be in a `table` environment and a graphics/diagram etc. must be contained in a `figure` environment.

However, `LaTeX` does not really care about the fact that the table might be included as an image 'only'. As long as the graphics format is the 'table' can be included as an image of course too.

The only relevance that is needed is the `\caption` which must appear inside the floating environment.

If the floating is not desired (or not possible), the `\captionof{floattype}{your caption title}` can be used instead -- this requires the very sophisticated `caption` package, however!

Either way the `caption` appears at the top if it is placed before the `\includegraphics` command -- no need to use weird `\newline` calls.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{graphicx}


\begin{document}
\listoftables
\clearpage
\begin{table}[ht]
\centering
\caption{Foo caption} \label{foo}
\includegraphics[scale=0.3]{ente}
\end{table}

Or using a \verb!\captionof! - command:

\begin{center}
\captionof{table}{Foobar caption} \label{foobar}
\includegraphics[scale=0.3]{ente}
\end{center}

There are two nice figures: \ref{foo} and \ref{foobar}
\end{document}
```

[image]